# How to extract exact name of a website with regex?

Tags: regex, go

This is to extract any website that is com or org, where www. is optional.
Does this make http:// a must and also I am failing to understand what [^.]+ means.

```
  ^http://(?:www\.)?[^.]+\.(com|org)/.*$
```

I want a specific website i.e:

```
  ^http://(?:www\.)?yahoo+\.(com|org)/.*$
```

thanks

Comment: You should try out your regex on https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html. This also includes a quick reference of regex syntax.

Comment: `[^.]+` means one or more characters that are not in the set (so any character except `.`). Also, your regex has `yahoo+`, which means you'll match `yahoo`, `yahooo`, `yahoooo`, etc.

Comment: ^http://(?:www\.)?yahoo\.(com|org)/.*$
So this would suffice?

Comment: nothing is appear in the match section of the regex tester not even .com

Comment: Can you give examples of inputs, some that match and some that don't?

Answer (score 2):

Please, use "net/url" package. It has [Hostname()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#example_URL_Hostname) method which allows you to extract the name of the host from any url.

In your case `[^.]` means any symbol except dot. Brackets define the symbol class. Plus after means one or more symbols after this class.
You can modify regex to look like (this will match all domains starting from yahoo):

```
^http://(?:www\.)?yahoo[^.]+\.(com|org)/.*$
```